# How to migrate Primefaces version from 6.2 to 11

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Is there any guide on migrating / updating/upgrading PrimeFaces from 6.2 to the latest 11 version?

Without damaging the code of course

I saw the main site of PRIMEFACES, and they say that a version can be uploaded gradually.
I used this site - https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide

But is there a shorter, faster, and safer way to upload a version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly upgrade the dependency to 11 (note that 12 is the most recent version), but you will still have to follow each migration guide in between.

Comment: Great! 
Do you know if there is a big difference 6.2 vs 12? 
something that cloud not work after the update?

Comment: Yes, there are many breaking changes which might depend on what components you are using. See the migration guides for details.